# Can a Content Security Policy be set for the SPA mode of NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy

I'm creating a site using Nuxt and I'm trying to set the CSP for the site. 
I am setting this via the csp property in the nuxt.config.js file.

My understanding of CSPs is that it is a header that is set by the hosting server. I know you can set them as a meta tag in HTML but I wish to set a report-URI for the policy.

Now I'm using the spa mode for Nuxt, so my thinking is that this csp setting is only for the SSR mode which would make sense. I can not find anywhere in the docs that explicitly says it's unavailable for a certain mode. 
[Link to Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render/#csp)

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to set this via the config file as I would prefer to do this instead of setting this on the hosting server.

Has anyone come across this in their experience with Nuxt?
Any insight into this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use Nuxt for this in SPA mode. Nuxt in SPA mode is just a bunch of static files and doesn't concern itself with the actual HTTP response.